# "with just enough beyond that" meaning

Tags: meaning-in-context

> In her old age she wanted to buy an annuity, ***with just enough beyond that*** so that she could afford to die at home.

I can't understand what is the meaning of "with just enough beyond that" in this sentence. what does that mean?

Comment: "Just enough" and "beyond" have their ordinary dictionary meanings. If a steak costs $10, and a cup of coffee costs $1, and I have $11, I have the price of a steak, with just enough beyond that to buy a cup of coffee.

Comment: Thank you so much I can understand now